# Designing a Mars-Class Zeppelin

Tags: science-based, engineering, planets

In my world, a scientist and engineer by the name of Guoliang Guan successfully uproots and moves a quarter of a million tons of habitat, industry, miscellaneous chemicals, storage containers, rocketry, life-support, and scientific experiments from all across the western hemisphere of Mars - to the bottom of [Valles Marineris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valles_Marineris) in two months. This accomplished with a mixture of dug-out roads, gondola lifts, concrete shoots, and a bachelors degree in Engineering. Due to his extraordinary accomplishments, Diego promotes him to Chief Mover of Stuff ... Arbiter of Transportation.

Now, Guoliang is greatful for his promotion and all,  but he considers it to be a real pain in the ass if he's gonna have to create new infrastructure every time he needs to move something from God-knows-where to Not-the-bottom-of-Valles-Marineris. So the thinks,  "Why make infrasture at all?", and dabbles in a mobile, vehicle-based transportation system. He starts by thinking of the all-terrainiest vechicle of them all; an airship, and reasons out its practicality in a dome at the top of Marineris.

Requirement~

- a useful lift capacity of 50 tons
- Maximum speed of 180 mph
- Operatable at 4 miles above the Martian surface level
- All requirements must be fufilled in relation to Mars

  ---

*My Question is:*

What modifications in ***Size*** (dimensions and volume), **Lift gas**, **Structure**, and **Propulsion** to the design of a normal airship (for this question, consider that base to be the [Zeppelin NT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeppelin_NT#Goodyear) or [LZ-130 Graf Zeppelin II](http://www.zeppelinhistory.com/list-of-zeppelins/lz-130-graf-zeppelin-2/)) would be necessary to met Guan's requirements?

*Points for factoring in the Martian Enviroment like sandstorms, air density, etc*

---

[Previous Question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/90590/) ~ [Next Question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/90854/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Impracticalities of making a Vacuum Airship](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/90713/impracticalities-of-making-a-vacuum-airship)

Comment: Seriously, stop posting duplicates.

Comment: Seriously, read the questions you call duplicates before calling them duplicates. I change the question as instructed by the site.

Comment: @Braydon While you're trying to be diligent, the OP is right. This question isn't about a vacuum airship. It's about a Marsworthy airship. Give the OP credit for trying to improve his question. If a question is called a duplicate I read it to make sure it is.

Comment: Would Guan be up for moving approximately an Earth Atmosphere's worth of gasses onto mars? It doesn't seem completely outrageous given his other requirements and it would definitely make air flight a lot easier to manage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

---

### Requirement A) Useful Lift Capacity of  50 tons

---

Given the Atmosphere of Mars is [0.02 kg/m^3](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/factsheet/marsfact.html) , and the densities of hydrogen and helium being $0.0004\text{kg/m}^3$ and $0.0008\text{kg/m}^3$ respectively*, Helium should lift $25\space \text{kilos per Kg of gas} (1250 \text{m}^3)$ on Mars, and Hydrogen $50\space\text{kilos per kg of gas} (2500 \text{m}^3)$; **making hydrogen the most practical choice** (especially since helium is rare on Mars, whereas hydrogen can be extracted from water). **This then gives us an airship of $2900000 \text{m}^3$ of hydrogen for it's 50 ton load, and using the proportions of the Zeppelin NT, one finds it need $3125000$ to carry it's own weight. This results in a diameter of $127.44$ meters and length of $675$ meters**

---

### Requirement B) Max Speed of 180 mph

---

Given the max speed of the Zeppelin NT    being 77mph with a mass of 10 tons and three engines of around 170 kw each, it can be deconstructed that with its Maximum loaded mass being around 110 tons, the Martian Airship would need a total of 13,260 horsepower to met this requirement in *Earth's* atmosphere. However, since Mars' atmosphere is over *60 times* less dense than Earth's, the total horsepower would need to be scaled up to $798,320$ total horse power to at 180 mph fully loaded through the Martian Air. This will require something on par with 3 [OK-650](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/OK-650_reactor) nuclear reactors.

* *The gas densities are given for STP on Mars ( -27° Celcius and 6.36 millibars )*

Comment: @ThroclesofSaturn; uhmm why are you scaling up *power* of engines compared with zeppelin's to compensate lower atmosphere density? You should scale up *propellers*, instead. Given lower density you'll have *less* drag (less power needed), but larger dimensions will partially counter this effect (square/cube law helps you, in this case!). In general I would expect less power requirements with larger propellers.

Comment: @ZioByte How much larger than proportion would the propellers on an Airship need to be to make up for the difference?

Comment: I would expect you need propeller *surface* to scale up to intercept (proximately) the same amount of gas, Then you should care for avoiding each blade to work in previous one turbulence as much as possible. I am stretching my knowledge, now, so please take this with a grain of salt as I'm not an avionics engineer (I'm a physicist). [NASA](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19980017535.pdf) seems to advise a three-blade design with relatively thin blades.

Comment: Two large counterrotating propellors extending from the stern of the airship might do for forward propulsion, and secondary propellors along the sides can be used for thrust vectoring and fine movements. Alternatively, given the vast surface area of the airship, perhaps energizing the surface and using it as an MHD wind accelerator will do (and is more SFNal as well).

Comment: By this calculations, since the atmosphere here on Earth is about 250 denser than Mars, you could lift 12,500 kg per kg of hydrogen or half as much with helium. If that were true, we would still be using zeppelins as freight carriers. Actually, given that Mars' gravity is 37% that of Earth, but its atmosphere is 250 times thinner I expect zeppelins to perform much worse than they do here.

Comment: @Rekesoft No, lift power doesn't scale like that. Earth's Atmosphere is 250 times denser, therefore hydrogen and helium of the same mass **take up 250 times less space due to greater pressure**. If Hydrogen and helium could exist at such low densities on earth, then yes, they would have 250 times their current lift power. **Remember Buoyancy is about displacement**. Mars' lower gravity, however, augments it's lift power per mass unit of gas because it has less weight per mass unit of cargo. A zeppelin would therefor be 2.7 times more efficient on mars than earth, but with 250 times the volume.

Comment: @TheoclesOfSaturn Oh, I see. Even then, 2.7 times more buoyancy with 250 time the volume doesn't seem to scale very well, does it? The zeppelin must have a rigid skeleton, and if it's 250 times bigger it's going to outweight its improved performance, imho.

Answer (score 1):

Since mars' atmosphere is thin enough to make a really good analog for hard vacuum in most laboratories here on earth,  there isn't any way to get buoyancy for a zeppelin. .